# IBAction Controlling too many actions

Tags: ios, xcode, ibaction

I am trying to make a tapper app and i have set up my action but it is controlling too many actions.  When I tap one tapper the value will go up in one label but not in the other, but when I tap the other tapper the value will go up in the other label. For example if one label has 3 and I hit the other tapper and it is at 0 it will go to 4.

h. file

```
{
BOOL newmedia;

IBOutlet UILabel *Label;
IBOutlet UILabel *LabelOne;
IBOutlet UIImage *myImageView;

int Number;


}

- (IBAction)Submit:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)openMail:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)Subtract:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)Addition:(id)sender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *grillretterScroller;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *rememberContentOffset;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textfield;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *AddNotesTextField;
@property(nonatomic,assign) id<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> mailComposeDelegate;
@property BOOL newmedia;
@property BOOL mailComposeController;
@end
```

m.file

```
 - (IBAction) Addition: (UIButton*) sender
 {
     const int firstButtonTag = 101;
     const int otherButtonTag = 102;

     if (sender.tag == firstButtonTag) {

         Number += 1;
         Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",Number];
}
     else if (sender.tag == otherButtonTag) {

         Number += 1;
         LabelOne.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",Number];
     }
 }
```

[image: Starts Equal]

[image: About to click button for label above 3 to go up]

[image: Button is clicked and image value increases one more than the other]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are using the same Number value for both the labels. You need to store the current value for each label.

Comment: I need it to go up by one each time @PallakG

Comment: @user3643316 access you labelvalue then incirment it by 1 then set again. like : `int NumberTemp = [Label.text integerValue]; NumberTemp += 1; Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",NumberTemp];`

Comment: so if i need 50 other buttons would i have to keep putting things in front of number  @ChinttuRoxeNRamani

Comment: @user3643316 No You can take global Number same as you take and initialize to 0 in `viewDidLoad`. your code is right i just show you another option. NSLog your number and check if you get incrimented number or not.